# Group by similar string

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case

Suppose I have a table like this

```
| id_grupo |    nombre       |
|:---------|----------------:|
| 1        | Emprendedores 1 |     
| 2        | Emprendedores 2 |    
| 3        | Emprendedoras 1 |      
| 4        | Emprendedoras 2 |         
| 5        | Los amigos 1    |       
| 6        | Los amigos 2    |
| 7        | Los amigos no 1 |
```

I want to group by name that are equal but **ends** in different number. If you look closely there are names which consists of two or more words however the difference is the ending. Also there are name which look similar but they are not the same like "Los amigos" and "Los amigos no", these belong to different groups, also "Emprendedores" and "Emprendedoras" are different.

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(id_grupo) 
FROM creabien_sacredi_dev.grupos
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(nombre,1,5)
```

It works fine with most of the records however the problem comes with strings like in the example which are very similar. I choose a substring with 5 characters but in fact names doesn't have the same length so some strings are not working as expected.

How can I group these strings in the following form?

```
    | id_grupo |    nombre       | GROUP_CONCAT(id_grupo) |
    |:---------|----------------:|-----------------------:|
    | 1        | Emprendedores 1 |  1,2                   |    
    | 3        | Emprendedoras 1 |  3,4                   |   
    | 5        | Los amigos 1    |  5,6                   |
    | 7        | Los amigos no 1 |  7                     |
```

I think the key is on the last number the preceding string must be exactly the same, but I don't know how to do it. Could you help me please?

**Edit:**

There are also records like 'Emprendedores' without any number at the end and this also should be grouped with 'Emprendedores 1' and 'Emprendedores 2'. So I think the number isn't anymore the key, in fact I doubt if there exist a way to group these records.

Comment: They're not the same the length - but the desired length is always one letter less than the actual length, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was looking for something like this: Emprendedores 10 but there it doesn't exist. So actually all records have one character than desired length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN RIGHT(nombre, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN 
         LEFT(nombre, Length(nombre) - 2) 
         ELSE nombre 
       END AS nombrechecked, 
       Group_concat(id_grupo) 
FROM   grupos 
GROUP  BY 1
```

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89fb9/2/0) that shows it works.

Comment: I haven't realized that there are records like 'Emprendedores' without the number which belong to the same group as 'Emprendedores 1' and 'Emprendedores 2', so this query wont' work. I'm editing my question. Sorry, my bad =(

Comment: *@Jorge Zapata*, I updated my answer to check for `nombre`s that don't have a number at the end.

Answer (score 1):

If items to cut are numbers only and  they are always separated by a space:

```
 SELECT CASE nombre REGEXP '[0-9]$'
        WHEN 1 THEN REVERSE (SUBSTR(REVERSE(nombre), 
                              INSTR(REVERSE(nombre),' '))) ELSE nombre END grupo, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(id_grupo)    
   FROM grupos
  GROUP BY grupo;
```

Just a proposal ... :) probably not the most performant. Advantage is, that it works with larger numbers at the end as well.

Check out [this Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d3cc/2).

Comment: I found that they not always end in number, I've just edited my quesiton. Sorry =(

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any entries like 'Los 2 amigos 1', then

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(id_grupo) 
FROM creabien_sacredi_dev.grupos
GROUP BY --replace digits with spaces
REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE(
nombre,
'0',' '),'1',' '),'2',' '),'3',' '),'4',' '),'5',' '),'6',' '),'7',' '),'8',' '),'9',' ')
```

Comment: Nice as well, however, I think you need a `TRIM` around the whole stuff ;)