# Trouble with Group By and Having in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to learn Group By and Having but I can't seem to understand what happened here. I used w3shools SQL Tryit Editor.

The table I created is:

```
name     age     country
------------------------
Sara     17      America
David    21      America
Jared    27      America
Jane     54      Canada
Rob      32      Canada
Matthew  62      Canada
```

The Query I used:

```
select 
    sum(age), country 
from 
    NewTable 
group by 
    country 
having 
    age>25;
```

I expected the query to categorize the information by country and use age>25 filter to create the results but here is the output:

```
sum(age)     country
--------------------
65           America
148          Canada
```

What happened?! The result is sum of American and Canadian people in all ages.

Comment: Think of having as a where clause that is applied AFTER the select (and the aggregation) completes.  So the results are exactly as expected.  the sum of all people's ages in America and Canada are both over 25; so both results show.  Normally I would alias the aggregrates so `sum(age) sumofage` and then say having sumofage >25.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by similar string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20222990/group-by-similar-string)

Comment: `having` is applied as a filter after the grouping has been done. It's useful for saying things like "sum all the ages grouped by country, then filter so that I only see the rows where the summed age is over 70". To achieve that, you would use `having sum(age)>70`. Your having clause has nothing to work on, so has no effect

Comment: In any other DBMS besides MySQL this will return an error message, because `HAVING` is evaluated *after* aggregation and there's no more individual age to compare to, only `AVG(age)` or any other aggregate function would be allowed here.

Answer (score 2):

The piece you're missing is specific to the `having` keyword.  Using the having clause in your query is applied to the dataset **after** the grouping occurs.

It sounds like you are expecting the records with age less than 25 to be excluded from your query before grouping occurs.  But, the way it works is the having clause excludes the total age for each group that sums to a total over 25.

If you want to exclude individual records before totaling the sum of the age, you could do something like this (using a `where` clause which is applied prior to grouping):

```
select sum(age), country from NewTable where age > 25 group by country;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MattLegler Can I ask another question? Suppose we have the same table columns with different rows and we execute the following query(It's a stupid query!) : select * from Table where age>10 group by country having age>20; So as you said, it should first select rows with age more than 10, then categorize them by country, and then kick out every group which even have only one row with age less than 20 even though other rows of that group are more than 20?!

Answer (score 1):

A `where` clause puts a condition on which rows participate in the results. 
A `having` clause is like a `where`, but puts a condition on which grouped (or  *aggregated*) values participate in the results.

Either, try this:

```
select sum(age), country 
from NewTable
where age > 25 -- where puts condition on raw rows
group by country
```

*or* this:

```
select sum(age), country 
from NewTable 
group by country 
having sum(age) > 25 -- having puts a condition on groups
```

depending on what you're trying to do.